# How to display the 5 images in UIImageview on button click in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one `UIImageview` and one `UIButton` and one `NSAarray` .I have assigned 5 images to that array.Now my question is how to display images one-by-one on button click for example, when we click the button first image should be displayed and if we click the that button again then second image should be displayed and so on.

Comment: you should need to maintain a flag or counter to display image at that index

Answer (score 1):

Use these below code on the button click.

```
if(sender.tag == 5){
    sender.tag = 0;
}

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:arrImage[sender.tag]];

sender.tag = sender.tag + 1
```

Comment: change to array count instead of directly giving five

Comment: That worked really well and was short, clean code Thanks. @suresh

Comment: @suresh If someone answer works for you then, accept his answer & up vote it, because it can be helpful for many other persons. Hope you keep in mind.  Welcome.  :)